# How to render redirect a URL with an int: parameter in Django views.py?

Tags: django, url, redirect, crud, url-parameters

I'm trying to make a form in Django that displays errors when the form isn't filled out properly under a specific account. I want it to reroute to the same page as the form, and the url has to have an int: parameter. For my urls.py, I have 'edit/int:user_id>, views.edit.

Where I'm struggling is how do I pass the render redirect in the views.py? I've tried render redirect('/edit/int:user_id'), ('/edit/int:user.id'), ('/edit/{user.id}'), etc, and NOTHING is working. Every time I just get 'path not found.'

How do I write  a redirect in views.py with an int parameter, based on what I have for my urlpatterns?

**views.py**

```
def update(request, user_id):
    errors = User.objects.empty_validator(request.POST)
    if len(errors):
        for key, value in errors.items():
            messages.error(request, value)
        return redirect('update_user', user.id)
    else:
        if 'user_id' in request.session:
            user = User.objects.get(id=job_id)
            user.title = request.POST['title']
            user.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard')
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Can you show you `urls.py` which specify the route you want to redirect ?

Comment: Here is my urls.py: path('/edit/<int:user_id>', views.edit),
    path('edit/<int:user_id>/update', views.update)       I have the user go to the /edit/<int:user_id> to submit the form. Whenever errors pop up from improperly completing the form, it's suppose to reroute the user back to the same page, with their user_id. I don't know how to write it into my views.py page though.

Comment: I just tried that, this is the error I got: Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/edit Using the URLconf defined in python_exam2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: create_user login logout dashboard new/create_form edit/<int:user_id> edit/<int:user_id>/update [name='update_user'] jobs/view/<int:user_id> delete/<int:user_id> The current path, user/edit/, didn't match any of these

Comment: For next times, it's better to edit your question to add the code of the needed elements (like urls, views, etc.) It' s easier for the one who tries to help you ;)

Comment: Sorry! This is my first time using StackOverflow or any forum for that matter, so I'm not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

First you should name your route by updating your `urls.py` :

```
path('edit/<int:user_id>/update', views.update, name='update_user')
```

Then, in your view, you can use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function like this :

```
redirect('update_user', user_id)
```

Comment: I just tried that, this is the error I got: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/edit/
Using the URLconf defined in python_exam2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

create_user
login
logout
dashboard
jobs/new
jobs/create_form
jobs/edit/<int:user_id>
edit/<int:user_id>/update [name='update_user']
jobs/view/<int:user_id>
delete/<int:user_id>
The current path, user/edit/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but here's my views.py: def update(request, user_id):
    errors = User.objects.empty_validator(request.POST)
    
    if len(errors):
        for key, value in errors.items():
            messages.error(request, value)
        return redirect('update_user', user.id)
    else:
        if 'user_id' in request.session:
            user = User.objects.get(id=job_id)
            user.title = request.POST['title']
            user.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard')
    return redirect('/')

Comment: Oh then you should replace `user.id` by `user_id`

Comment: I just changed it to user_id, and this is the error I got: MultiValueDictKeyError at /edit/4/update
'title'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/4/update
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError                                            Sorry to keep bugging you, and thank you for your help by the way! I appreciate it!!

Comment: @Crystal that appears to be a different question. Also as suggested by Benbb96 you should edit your question to add any code / clarification. You can do that by pressing the edit button just below your post / question.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry! I've never used StackOverflow before.

Comment: Hum that seems to be a bug from this line `user.title = request.POST['title']`. Maybe try to replace by `user.title = request.POST.get('title', 'Default Title')`